# Check current date between two dates of table value

Tags: mysqli

i have a table and have 4 columns

```
id     name     from_date     to_date
1      vivek    2018-11-12    2018-11-22
2      abc      2018-10-11    2018-10-21
```

from date and to date is date when my users are allowed to access the website paid data so i want to retrieve data of those user who is able to see my paid data today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CURDATE()` might be useful here:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN from_date AND to_date;
```

This answer assumes that the range from `from_date` to `to_date` represents a range *inclusive* on both ends.  If not, then the query would change slightly.

Comment: yes it's working but if my current date is equal to from date or to date then it's not returning i want that time too

Comment: what would be query if i need to include both ends

Comment: What you are describing makes no sense.  Are `from_date` and `to_date` both pure date columns?  If so, my answer should be working.

Comment: My answer already includes both ends.  Your data has some problem.